# An ODE system containing Riccati's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE system containing Riccati's equation as follows.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{dy}{dt} &=
    q_{2} \, y^{2} + q_{1}(t) \, y + q_{0}(t)
\\[1.5ex]
\dfrac{dz}{dt} &=
    p_{1}(t) \, z + p_{0} \, y
\end{aligned}
$$

where

$$
\begin{aligned}
q_{0}(t) &=
    b + \alpha \, z(t)
\\[1.5ex]
q_{1}(t) &=
    a - p_{0} + \beta \, z(t)
\\[1.5ex]
p_{1} &= - \alpha - \beta \, y(t)
\end{aligned}
$$

and $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $q_{2}$, $p_{0}$ are constants.

I know it's straightforward to follow the instructions on the [wiki's webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#:%7E:text=More%20generally%2C%20the%20term%20Riccati,as%20the%20algebraic%20Riccati%20equation.) to develop a Bernoulli equation for Riccati's equation. But after that, I got stuck on how to consider the other differential equation.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me or provide some hints.

Comment: It is not a nice idea to use the unknowns as part of coefficients that are in general assumed to be fixed. So you got rather generic quadratic polynomials in $y,z$ on the right side. In most cases, there is no symbolic reduction available.

Comment: Since the system is autonomous, you can 'reduce" it to a rather nasty first-order equation for $z$ as a function of $y$ or vice versa, but AFAIK this won't have closed-form general solutions. Maple doesn't find any.  There are fixed points where $y$ is a root of  $q_2 y^2 + a y + b$ (of course these roots may or may not be real), and $z = p_0 y/(\beta y + \alpha)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can you provide more details, please? For me, any method, rather than resorting to pure numerical iteration like RK4, could be my choice.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It seems to be a possible way to find the particular solution but still leave the general solutions unknown, isn't it?

Comment: @LutzLehmann BTW, a, b, α, β, q2, p0 are all priorly known real-valued constants. Does this make the situation better?

Comment: What is your objective for the solution, what do you want to use it for? Almost every solution requires numerical approximation, in the "nice" cases it is transcendental functions, integrals like the error function, implicit equations. All else requires numerical integration. It is only that these nice, manually solvable cases have such a weight in the introductory courses that an opposite impression is given.

Comment: That was already factored in. Even finding the constant solutions requires a numerical solver. The context of that is to use shifting and scaling to find a normal form of the system, so that the solution space needs to be explored once to get valid insights for all systems in this class. But I suspect that the normal form will still not be simple enough to make a nice theory like in the Riccati equations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am comparing a kinetic model to my experimental observations. To directly simulate the solutions and compare them to the data is typically what I used to do. However, recently I somehow started to think if I could fit the whole model to the observations. So I began to try to find an analytic solution such that the computational force can be reduced. But now, it seems to be hard to achieve. As you mentioned, is there any suggested way to approximate the solution of this system?

Comment: I rather doubt the search for a normal form will go far enough. As the model is most likely only locally a good fit for the physical dynamic, I would recommend to split the data set into several reasonably short pieces and fit for a separate solution on all of them, using the same parameters, but obviously not compatible initial conditions. Additionally fit a global solution, but with less weight in the square sum of residuals. A situation where that becomes essential is present in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722061/trying-to-infer-model-parameter-of-lotka-volterra-model

Comment: Thanks for your suggested post that prevented me from using any analytical method for my questions. By the way, recently, I found that the "system identification of nonlinear state-space models" might be another potential for solving such an intractable ODE system as a reference for who may come into this thread.